# Mathematica crashing on Solve (finding points on 4 circles on a sphere). How to reformulate?

Tags: equation-solving

I define a small circle on a unit sphere by the direction of the plane's normal and its distance to the sphere center (i.e. origin) like this (parametrized by the angle t):

```
sphereCircleRadiusFromOfs[ofs_] := Sqrt[1 - ofs^2];
pointOnSphereCircle[dir_, ofs_] := dir*ofs + Normalize@Cross[Cross[{0, 1, 0}, dir], dir] * sphereCircleRadiusFromOfs[ofs];
sphereCircle[dir_, ofs_, t_] := dir + RotationMatrix[t, dir].(pointOnSphereCircle[dir, ofs] - dir);
```

Now, given 4 such circles with plane normals towards the 4 vertices of a regular tetrahedron and a distance of 1/Sqrt[2], I want to find solutions for the 4 angles such that the sums of the 4 points on the 4 circle are {0,0,0}.

I attempt to this by:

```
ofs = 1/Sqrt[2];
sol = Solve[
  sphereCircle[Normalize@{+1, +1, +1}, ofs, tPPP] + 
  sphereCircle[Normalize@{+1, -1, -1}, ofs, tPNN] + 
  sphereCircle[Normalize@{-1, +1, -1}, ofs, tNPN] + 
  sphereCircle[Normalize@{-1, -1, +1}, ofs, tNNP] == {0, 0, 0}, {tPPP, tPNN, tNPN, tNNP}]
```

Unfortunately, Mathematica keeps computing forever, consuming more and more memory and will eventually crash. Is there a way to reformulate the problem such that Mathematica is more successful in solving it ?

Comment: the vertices {+1, +1, +1}, {+1, -1, -1}, {-1, +1, -1}, {-1, -1, +1} do form a regular tetrahedron. why do you think they do not ?

Comment: Sorry, I made an error with the signs.

Answer (score 4):

It's unlikely there is an analytic solution to this with all those Sin and Cos functions. But it looks like you would be happy with a numerical solution. One simple way to proceed is to use NMinimize:

```
sol = NMinimize[Total[sphereCircle[Normalize@{+1, +1, +1}, ofs, tPPP] + 
 sphereCircle[Normalize@{+1, -1, -1}, ofs, tPNN] + 
 sphereCircle[Normalize@{-1, +1, -1}, ofs, tNPN] + 
 sphereCircle[Normalize@{-1, -1, +1}, ofs, tNNP]]^2, {tPPP, tPNN, tNPN, tNNP}]

{7.70372*10^-34, {tPPP -> 1.35117, tPNN -> 0.0998971, tNPN -> 1.22328, tNNP -> 2.48563}}
```

Comment: thank you. that is a good start. however, i was hoping to get some insight about the relationship of the 4 angles to produce the desired zero-vector output.

Comment: I suggest plotting the angles to see how they change with ofs. I suspect that a good visualization of the numerical solution is the best that is going to be possible.

Answer (score 2):

If the sum of the points is zero, this implies that if we project the points onto any plane, the sum of the planar coordinates must also sum to zero. This only leaves symmetrical arrangements. And with symmetrical solutions, the problem becomes easy. I have no mathematical proof for this, but at worst, we may miss additional solutions.

With:

```
r = 1/Sqrt[2];
te = Normalize /@ {{+1, +1, +1}, {+1, -1, -1}, {-1, +1, -1}, {-1, -1, \
+1}};
sphereCircleRadiusFromOfs[ofs_] := Sqrt[1 - ofs^2];
pointOnSphereCircle[dir_, ofs_] := 
  dir*ofs + 
   Normalize@Cross[Cross[{0, 1, 0}, dir], dir]*
    sphereCircleRadiusFromOfs[ofs];
sphereCircle[dir_, ofs_, t_] := 
  dir + RotationMatrix[t, dir].(pointOnSphereCircle[dir, ofs] - dir);
```

We can look at the points:

```
cir[t_] = sphereCircle[#, r, t] & /@ te;
Manipulate[
 Show[
  ParametricPlot3D[cir[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], 
  Graphics3D[{{Opacity[0.5], Sphere[]}, Red, PointSize[0.02], 
    Point@sphereCircle[#, r, t] & /@ te
    }], PlotRangePadding -> None, ImageSize -> 400]
 , {t, 0, Pi}]
```

[image]

We can now define a function of the angles that adds the points and plot it as a function of the angle. x and z coordinates add always up to zero due to the vector {0,1,0} in `pointOnSphereCircle`. The sum of the y coordinates:

```
fu[t_] := Total[sphereCircle[#, r, t][[2]] & /@ te]
Plot[fu[t], {t, 0, Pi}]
```

[image]

From the plot and from symmetry it is clear, that `Pi/2`is a solution:

```
fu[Pi/2] // N
(* {0., -8.32667*10^-17, 5.55112*10^-17} *)
```